# php runtime error memory size exhausted

Tags: php

When I import mysql.sql.zip file,I got following errors

```
<br /> <b>Fatal error</b>: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 128974893 bytes) in <b>C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\export.php</b> on line <b>133</b><br />
```

Comment: Your file is too big.  Also, that's a `Fatal error`, not a `Syntax error`.  There's a huge difference.

Comment: how are you trying to import that file? are you using some GUI (phpMyAdmin) ?? how big is the file?

Comment: @PachinSV: I'd assume so, since the error is from `phpMyAdmin\export.php`.

Comment: That's a **PHP** runtime error, not a MySQL syntax error. You'll find hundreds of dupes here.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is too big, you should import it using the console.

First extract the .sql file and if the scripst creates the database use this command

```
mysql -u myUserName -p < file.sql
```

Or if the database already exists use this one:

```
mysql -u myUserName -p databaseName < file.sql
```

I'm assuming that the user "myUserName" has a password that's why I added the -p.

Answer (score -1):

Extract the file and try to split it in 2 parts and import each part separately. There should be more than one query in it, so you should be able to split it easily